# MySQL: Join to many: select sums in both tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem. I want to join a table in a query. This table has multiple records. Now, I want the sum of a column in the main table, and the sum of a column in the joined table. This leads to problems, because the sum of the column in the main table is now incorrect (because I join to multiple rows).

```
| id | date       | campaign_id | sessions |
|----|------------|-------------|----------|
| 1  | 2019-07-01 | 1           | 10       |
| 2  | 2019-07-02 | 1           | 20       |
```

Joined table:

```
| id | some_var | campaign_id | some_other_metric |
|----|----------|-------------|-------------------|
| 1  | a        | 1           | 100               |
| 2  | b        | 1           | 200               |
| 3  | c        | 1           | 300               |
```

Query:

```
select table_a.campaign_id, SUM(table_a.sessions), SUM(table_b.some_other_metric)
FROM table_a
left join table_b ON table_a.campaign_id = table_b.campaign_id)
group by table_a.campaign_id
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
| campaign_id | SUM(table_a.sessions) | SUM(table_b.some_other_metric) |
|-------------|-----------------------|--------------------------------|
| 1           | 30                    | 600                            |

SUM(table_a.sessions) = 30
SUM(table_b.some_other_metric) = 600
```

But I am getting other results:

```
SUM(table_a.sessions) = 90
SUM(table_b.some_other_metric) = 1200
```

Is there a different way to join this tables to get the result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `select DISTINCT(table_a.id).....,`

Comment: *"Try select DISTINCT(table_a.id)....., "* @MoisheSchwartz DISTINCT is not a function and what you write does not make sense..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward approach is to use separate subqueries to aggregate the sums in each of the two tables:

```
SELECT
    a.campaign_id,
    COALESCE(a.sessions_sum, 0) AS session_sum,
    COALESCE(b.other_sum, 0) AS other_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT campaign_id, SUM(sessions) AS sessions_sum
    FROM table_a
    GROUP BY campaign_id
) a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT campaign_id, SUM(some_other_metric) AS other_sum
    FROM table_b
    GROUP BY campaign_id
) b
    ON a.campaign_id = b.campaign_id;
```

The above approach has the potential drawback that any `campaign_id` which appears *only* in `table_b` would be dropped from the result set.  But, it is no worse than your current left join approach.  Ideally, you could use a third table which contains all `campaign_id` values which you want to appear in the result set.

Comment: Good answer +1 *" Ideally, you could use a third table which contains all campaign_id values which you want to appear in the result set"*  @EelceLuurtsema i would use a delivered table as using/maintaining a table for output results/filtering in my opinion is not really justified .. More or less like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/doY93qQHFTJNvGER7TvNA7/4) .. (updated fiddle link as it was wrong)

Comment: Thanks for both solutions, they give back the correct results. I am a little worried about performance though, is the performance of both these queries good when using on tables with millions of rows?

Comment: @EelcoLuurtsema There isn't much that can be done performance wise.  The sum operation in this query requires basically handling each record.